# How to use acronym for helper module name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model which name is acronym, so I configured like:

#### config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
    inflect.acronym 'GNU'
end
```

And I created helper module for that model.

#### app/helpers/gnus/gnus_helper.rb

```
module GNUsHelper
end
```

Then I got error `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant GnusHelper`.

It seems Rails are looking for camel case module.

How can I use acronym helper module in Rails?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still wondering about this.  Simply define the acronym and its plural version, like this:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'GNU'
  inflect.acronym 'GNUs'
end
```

In this case, ActiveSupport is reading GNUsHelper as 2 separate words delimited by camelcase ("GNUs" and "Helper").  You'll have to also define "GNUs" as an acronym for this to work.

Also, there's no need to call `inflect.titleize`, `inflect.camelize`, or `inflect.underscore` within the `ActiveSupport.inflections` block.  (everything inside the block defines inflection rules for your entire application and titlelize is not a rule)

The documentation suggests defining pluralized versions of acronyms to avoid problems like this one.

***From the docs***

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym

Note: Acronyms that are passed to pluralize will no longer be recognized, since the acronym will not occur as a delimited unit in the pluralized result. To work around this, you must specify the pluralized form as an acronym as well:

```
acronym 'API'
camelize(pluralize('api')) #=> 'Apis'

acronym 'APIs'
camelize(pluralize('api')) #=> 'APIs'
```

Answer (score -2):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym

It looks like you may need to specify the other forms of this word.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym    'GNU'
  inflect.titleize   'GNU'     
  inflect.camelize   'GNU'     
  inflect.underscore 'GNU' 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I got a error when I restart rails server. ``undefined method `titleize' for #<ActiveSupport::Inflector::Inflections:0x007fbd239da020> (NoMethodError)``

Comment: Did you get this one fixed?

Comment: No, I gave up to use acronym's helper method.

Comment: This was never part of the API, at least from Rails 4+